# Set max height on dijit.Menu

Tags: javascript, css, dojo

I have one popup subMenu using dijit.menu that can be very long due to dynamic input. I want to set a max Height and `overflow-y:auto` to dijit.menu. So it will has a scroll bar when becoming too long.

```
var subMenu  = new dijit.Menu({ parentMenu: this.mainMenu});

//....add a lots of submenu items here

this.mainMenu.addChild(new dijit.PopupMenuItem({label: "some label", popup: subMenu}));
```

The problem is the top level of dijit.menu is a `<table>`, and `max-height` won't work on it. Also, unlike `dijit.form.select`, the dijit.menu does not take `maxHeight` as a parameter.

I noticed there is a ticket describing this problem on dojo long time ago and marked as fixed. However, I still have no idea how to set maxheight on the menu.(The fix seems no longer exsits too)

[Ticket #9086 (Allow CSS height on dijit.Menu)](http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/9086)

Any hint on how I might able to do this would be apperciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you noted, there is an issue with the way that Dojo handles the DOM creation of the `dijit.Menu` widget. The problem isn't that `maxHeight` isn't accepted as a parameter (as you can just pass it into the widget's `style` property as part of an Object or String), rather how the styling is applied.

You mentioned that the "top level" of a `Menu` widget is the `<table>` node. However, this is not the whole truth. That node is what Dojo presents to the client (you) as the "top level" `domNode`, but the `Menu` actually wrapped in another `<div>` that you cannot access directly from the widget, and it is this node that your styles *should* be applied to.

This `<div>` has the attribute `class="dijitPopup dijitMenuPopup"`, but I doubt you want to set your styles to Dijit popups/menus globally. To avoid this, you can set the `baseClass` property on your widget as follows:

```
new Menu({
    baseClass: "myCustomMenu",
    targetNodeIds: ["myTarget"]
});
```

This will change that top level `<div>` attribute to read `class="dijitPopup myCustomMenuPopup"`. This gives you a class that you can modify with the CSS styles you need to accomplish your goal:

```
.myCustomMenuPopup {
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/H7Zh8/44/) in jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks you for the amazing answer! I have spent a lot time trying to find out how to access this div in menu widget without luck...

Comment: No problem, glad I was able to help :) As an aside, if you do need direct access to that `<div>`, you could just access the domNode's parent element.